# Problem About deleting the pycharm installation package

Tags: ubuntu, installation, pycharm

I'm looking to install pycharm on my ubuntu virtual machine, it's actually not hard. But I'm not sure whether I can delete the unzipped installation package. I will put the picture of the installation package below. My confusion is:

1. Can I delete the installation package of unzipped pycharm?
2. I would like to summarize the rules appropriately. For this kind of software that is downloaded and installed from the official website, can I safely delete it after the installation is completed?

The above question may sound stupid, but I still want your opinions and suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are free to remove the `tar.gz` archive indeed. You cannot remove the unpacked IDE though - it is basically PyCharm itself. Might be a good idea to move it from `Downloads` to a better place, e.g. `/opt`. See the official instruction https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installation-guide.html#standalone

P.S.: You are using a 5 years old PyCharm version.